# Handling AGC (Automatic Gain Control) VoiceRecognition?

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition, basic4android

How can we handle the [automatic gain control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_gain_control) of VoiceRecognition with code?

If I'm not mistakened, [source.Android.com's article](http://source.android.com/devices/audio_implement.html#preprocessing) explains that in voicerecognition the AGC is not enabled, yet but in my HTC, after running the VoiceRecognition I noticed that AGC is running.